# Where to place output button below file field

Tags: alignment, file-input, browse

[image]I have multiple function which includes one or two file as inputs and a file as an output.
I am not sure how to align the output button.

1. Right align with the browse button of the field
2. Left align with the field
3. Center align to the control of browsing file(which contains both file field and'browse' button).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this problem.

But to answer your question more visually: left-align the buttons.
You can actually convert the 4 components (label, input field, placeholder and browse button) into just 2 (icon and an actionable call-to-action).

[image]